# PHP blank page after the login

Tags: php

I'm building a CMS for a website. The problem is that after the login a blank page appears and it stays until I hit refresh. Then it loads to the correct menu page and everything else is working correctly except this little detail. Any tips to solve this? Thanks, my code is below:

```
    <?php

session_start();

include_once('../includes/connection.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    //display index
    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>AdminENG</title>
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="../assets/style.css"/>
    </head>

        <body>
            <div class="container">
                CMS - ENG
                <ol>

                    <li><a href ="add.php">Add Article</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="delete.php">Delete Article</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>

    <?php
}
else {
    //display login
    if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);

        if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
            $error = "All fields are required!";
        }
        else {
            $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ? AND user_password = ?");

            $query->bindValue(1, $username);
            $query->bindValue(2, $password);

            $query->execute();

            $num = $query->rowCount();

            if($num == 1) {
                //user entered the correct details
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

                header('Location: index.php');
                exit();
            }
            else {
                //user entered false details
                $error = "Incorrect details!";
            }
        }
    }

    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>AdminENG</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="../assets/style.css"/>
    </head>

        <body>
            <div class="container">
                CMS
                <br><br>

                <?php
                if (isset($error)) { ?>
                    <small style="color:#aa0000"><?php echo $error; ?></small>

                <?php } ?>

                <br><br>

                <form action="index.php" method="post">
                    <input type ="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>

    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: are you working on a local machine (lamp/mamp/xampp)? Did you check your php.ini error settings show you possible errors? That might help you debugging.

Comment: Also take note of the manual: `For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement.`

Comment: Actualt this doesn't happen on localhost, just notice  this after the upload

Comment: And `md5()` is not a good way to protect / store your passwords, use a salted hash with a good hashing algorithm, see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `Header` after you execute html to the browser.
Try replace this: `header('Location: index.php');`

With this:

`<script>window.location="index.php";</script>`

Comment: Good, your welcome. By the way I was wrong didn't see the `if` in your code. You has the same problem, but it wasn't because of the `html` tags. probably because of the whitespaces on top as one of the answers point out.

Comment: @Miguel You should solve the problem, not switch to another language to hide it.

Answer (score 4):

Your `header()` redirection is probably not working. Check error log to see what the problem is. There must be absolutely no characters sent to the browser before the `header()` redirection, else it will fail.

My guess would be that those few spaces before `<?` in your script (if they are not copy/paste error) could interfere with `head()` redirection.

Anyway, check your `error.log` and see what do you have there.

Comment: Sorry for my ignoarance but how can i check error log?

Comment: You should see where your errors are stored if you create blank php file and execute `phpinfo()` in it. Among other data there should be error log location. If you are on shared hosting, it's most likely `error_log` file in the directory where php resides, or in root (public_html) directory. If you are administering your server, it could be in `/var/log/apache2` or wherever you set it to be. Also, you can see the location by checking in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: Or put this at the top of your script: `ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`